# Hash function for string with complexity O(N)

Tags: algorithm, hash, computer-science, hashcode

For example we have a string: "abc". Is it possible to create a hash function (with complexity O(N), where N is string length) that will do the following: for all permutation for string "abc" it will return the same result.

**For example:**

```
hash("abc") returns SC0wA //just an example value, not a real hash key
hash("bac") returns SC0wA
...
hash("cba") returns SC0wA
```

But for "bba" it will be:

```
hash("bba") return GD1z
hash("bab") return GD1z
```

UPD:

Hash function should not have any collisions for the whole alhpabet

Comment: What is the whole alphabet? Is it just lower case letters?

Comment: @Sean aA..zZ letters

Comment: How many different strings are you trying to hash, and what are the typical lengths? Perhaps more to the point, what is the larger problem you're trying to solve that you think you need this type of hash code?

Comment: @NoNameYp - I've updated my answer to include a solution that I think does what you want.

Comment: @JimMischel In common case each string length is N (always!), strings count is K. But let's assume (simple case) that we have 10 string with length 4 chars each.

Comment: The reason I ask about number of strings and their lengths is because if we can assume certain limits then we can tailor a solution. For example, if your strings are 4 characters, then you can trivially sort the characters using a sorting network (4 items sort in 5 comparisons), and then treat the result as a unique 32-bit (or 64-bit if you're using Unicode) integer. But if your strings are 40 characters long then you'll have to come up with something better to deal with inevitable collisions.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could do it like this, in C# :

```
string text = "abc";
int hash = 0;

foreach(char c in text)
{
  int value = (int)c;
  hash += value;
}
```

The distribution of the hash value won't be great, but it does the job.

UPDATE: Since you've mentioned that the alphabet just consists of `A-Z` and `a-z` then another option is to map their position in the alphabet to bits in a `long`, with the uppercase characters taking up the first 26 bits and the lower case characters taking up the next 26 bits:

```
long MakeHash(string text)
{
    long hash = 0;
    long numberOfCharacters = 0;

    foreach(var c in text)
    {
        int offset = 0;

        if(c >= 'A' && c <='Z')
        {
            offset = c - 'A';
        }
        else
        {
            offset = (c - 'a') + 26;
        }

        hash |= (1L << offset);

        numberOfCharacters++;
    }

    hash |= (numberOfCharacters << 52);

    return hash;
}
```

Note how at the end the number of characters is OR'd into the bits 52 and beyond. Without this strings like `aa` and `aaa` would map to the same value as they'd all just set the `a` bit. With the length combined into the value you get a different value.

Comment: This way, "ad" and "bc" will have the same hash value. Usually, "hash" implies that objects which are not explicitly required to have the same hash are unlikely to.

Comment: @Gassa - yes, but it's also not an error for 2 objects to have the same hash code, either!

Comment: That's a strange logic; by it, the "return 0" hash function does not have any errors either.

Comment: Whereas hash collisions are inevitable when hashing strings, the algorithm you propose has an incredibly high collision rate.

Comment: @JimMischel - yes, it does. However, given the restrictions in the question there has to be some sort of compromise, and that's one of them.

Answer (score 2):

One simple algorithm could be:

```
int x = 0;
int s = 0;
for each character c in the string str
{
 x = x ^ c
 s = s + ASCII value of c
}

hash(str) = x + s
```

**Collisions Handling**

The reason I added the value `s` in the final answer is because suppose we have two strings `s1 = "ab"` and `s2 = "ef"`, they would result in a collision just by `xor` operation,however after we add the value of sum of their `ASCII values`, they do not result in collision.

The `xor` operation also helps to avoid collision when sum of `ASCII values` of the characters is same. Suppose we have `s1 = "ad"` and `s2 = "bc"`. By only considering the sums of `ASCII values`, it would result in collision but after the considering the `xor` operation as well it does not.

Also for strings of even length like "aaaa" and "bbbb" , if we only consider the `xor` operations, still we have collision but by adding the sums of `ASCII values`, we can avoid the collision.

**So combining the sum of ASCII values of characters of the string and the xor operation, collision can be handled to a larger extent.**

Comment: for "ac" and "bb" function returns the same value

Comment: @NoNameYp For ac, the answer is 198 = 97+99 +a^c and for bb the answer is  196 = 98 + 98 + b^b

Comment: @NoNameYp How are 198 and 196 same value?

Comment: The strings "AR" and "BQ" hash to the same value. "AS" and "BR" will hash to the same value, etc. This method might generate fewer collisions than just adding the ASCII values of the characters, but it's still not great.

Comment: @JimMischel Thanks for pointing that out. I never said my algorithm is collision free.

Comment: No, you didn't say it was collision free. You said that "collision can be handled to a larger extent." I was just pointing out, to others and possibly to you, that the chance of collision is higher than might be apparent.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you want the hash of a [multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset).
If there are no other requirements, such as fast recalculation for substrings or concatenation, you can just do the following:

1. Build some canonic representation of the multiset as a string: a string which is the same for every object you consider the same, and different for objects you consider different. For that, just sort the characters of the string. For a small alphabet (English only? ASCII?), this can be done with [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) in O(N) time and O(|A|) memory where A is the alphabet: just calculate in a single pass how many of each letter you have. Admittedly, this won't go so well for larger alphabets, as you'll need a usual sort with O(N log N) time complexity.
2. Now, just calculate the usual polynomial hash of the string you got. That is, for a string S = s<sub>0</sub>s<sub>1</sub>...s<sub>n-1</sub>, the hash is s<sub>0</sub>p<sup>n-1</sup> + s<sub>1</sub>p<sup>n-2</sup> + ... + s<sub>n-1</sub>p<sup>0</sup> mod q for some primes p and q. From the array of size |A| where you store how many of each letter was there, you can construct the sorted string on-the-fly, thus not needing an additional O(n) space for it. This step works in O(n + |A|).

Answer (score 0):

If the O(N) requirement doesn't matter too much, here's what I propose : sort the string, then use a native hash method :

```
char[] characters=inputString.toCharArray();
Arrays.sort(characters);
return new String(characters).hashCode();
```

As Alper commented, this is a O(N * log(N)) solution due to the sort complexity.

[Here](https://ideone.com/ytVNvi)'s a Java ideone to test it.

---

If the O(N) requirement is important but collision isn't, you can just use any commutative operation, for example addition of the char values. The problem with that example solution is that you'll end up with the same result for "bc" and "ad", or "abb" and "aac".

Comment: @Alper you're right. I'm not sure I'll be able to find an O(N) solution or disprove its existence so I'll just add a disclaimer.

Comment: @Aaron: generic sorting algorithms are NlogN, but specialized sorts can easily be O(n). Like... a counting sort.

Comment: @MooingDuck A counting sort is exactly what I propose in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37987671/1488799).

Comment: @Aaron Collision resistance is a requirement of any hash function; otherwise, you could just return `0` for all inputs.

Comment: @augurar it is indeed important, but sacrifices are often made for practical purposes. Every hashing function accepting variable-width data and producing fixed-width hashes (such as md5, sha1 and Java's default hashcodes) will have some collision because its output domain is smaller than its (infinite) input domain

Answer (score 0):

With Aggregation of the hashcodes of the chars, the order would not matter. e.g.:

```
var hash = text.Aggregate(text.Length, (h,c) => h | c.GetHashCode()); //NB "aab" == "bba"
```

Base is `text.Length`, so "aaa" != "aa" etc.
But this still results in "aab" == "bba".

Instead of | other variations are possible, such as XOR, but then "aa" == "bb" (because the result would be 0).

Perhaps reoccurring chars is not a problem (?) , otherwise ordering or grouping the chars is needed. Easiest would be to create a new string with the ordered chars, but that is heavier on processing/memory.
To order by and aggregate in one go, this could work:

```
var hash = text.OrderBy(c=>c).Aggregate(text.Length, (h,c) => (h << 1) ^ c.GetHashCode());
```

(The hash << 1 is to make sure "aab" !== "abb")
But more efficient versions could be made if there are strict rules on the possible permutations.
Not completely O(n) of course. You could come closer to O(n) with counting occurrences (collisions) of the same hash (char), but I reckon the branching that causes, would imply a heavier hit on performance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Compute the sums s1, s2, ..., sn of each of the n possible input symbols in your string
2. Consider the unary (base 1) representations thereof: u1, u2, ..., un. We'll take the unary representation of a number n to be the string 0^n.
3. Construct a binary string hash = (u1)1(u2)1...1(un)
4. Interpret hash as the binary representation of a number of string and use a hash with your properties

If x and y have the same number of symbol k, then uk will be the same; and if this is true for all 1 <= k <= n then the hashes must be the same. It is also easy to show that strings that have different counts will have different hashes.

How big are these hashes? When the total number of symbols in the input is zero, the output is 1^n of length n bits. When you add a symbol to the input, one count increases by one, one unary representation increases in length by 1, and the overall size of the hash increases by one bit. So an input string of length m will have length m+n bits.

This algorithm is O(m+n) time and space where n is the fixed number of input symbols and m is the number of elements in the input string.

EDIT: An example would help.

Say that the input alphabet is `A = {a, b, c, d, e}`. We impose an ordering on the set to get the sequence `L = (a, b, c, d, e)`. So `L(0) = a, L(1) = b`, etc. Now we want to hash the following two strings: `abcd` and `bcda`.

We record the partial sums in unary (note that the result is the same for both strings):

```
u1 = 0
u2 = 0
u3 = 0
u4 = 0
u5 = (empty)
```

We construct the hash as follows: `(u1)1(u2)1(u3)1(u4)1(u5)1 = 010101011`.

So the hash of both strings is equal to 171 when the output of the above procedure is interpreted as the binary encoding of an integer. If interpreted as a string over the input alphabet of size `5`, `171 = 1*125 + 1*25 + 4*5 + 1*1` and thus we can encode it as `bbeb`. To be explicit, we are considering the input alphabet to be digits of a base-5 encoding of numbers where the digit x is equal to x's place in the ordering of the alphabet. So `a = 0`, `b = 1`, `c = 2`, `d = 3`, `e = 4`. The number `bbeb` is therefore equal to `1*5^3 + 1*5^2 + 4*5^1 + 1*5^0 = 125 + 25 + 20 + 1 = 171`.

One might object that this is going to produce a hash that is similar in length to the input. If you want one that's fixed length, just run a hash on the output of this one that has the properties you want. Then the composition will be a hash function that you like.

Comment: An example would help. Given the string "abcd", what would the hash value be?

Comment: I think there at the end the `121` should be `171`. And I understand how you got "171" out of "abcd". But how you got "bbeb" out of "171" is not at all clear. In any case, The length of your hash is unmanageable if the alphabet or the string length is more than trivially short. If I understand your algorithm, a 10 character string over an alphabet of 64 characters will result in a 74 bit hash.

Comment: @JimMischel A 10 character string over a 64 character alphabet is already 60 bits long. The hash in this case is 14 bits longer than the input. For long enough strings, the hash will be shorter than the input. You want a shorter or fixed-length hash? Run any hash you want on the output of this one and use that result as your hash. I'll do one more edit to correct the 121 problem and explain a little more where `bbeb` comes from.

Comment: But if I hash a hash, then my collision rate increases even more. Plus, the idea of hashing a 4-character string over a 256 character alphabet resulting in a 260 bit result is ... well, unique in my experience. Sure, if your strings are long enough you'll save space. But I suspect most uses won't realize that savings.

Comment: @JimMischel The collision rate of my method is zero (no unintended collisions, that is), so the hash of my hash will have whatever collision rate the other hash algorithm does (unless you compose with itself, then you will get collisions). It's not unusual for a hash of a small string to produce a larger string; as far as I know all cryptographic hash functions have this behavior. There are 256 symbols in the alphabet of values of an 8-bit variable, so any binary file of a size significantly greater than 256 bytes in length could be shorter, even much shorter.